# How can I access a local variable from another module in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, local-variables

I wanna create a logout function that should reset all the counters. Therefore, I need to access the countervariables from another module (and set them to the original value). How can I do that within javascript and react?

Here is my import declaration and the logoutUser function from the AuthState.js file:

```
import chatState from "../Chat/ChatState";

const logoutUser = () => {
    console.log(questioncounter);
    chatState.questioncounter = 2;
    chatState.questioncounter_event = 1;
    chatState.currentNode = 1;

    dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT_USER,
    });
  };
```

And here are the local variables from ChatState.js:

```
let questioncounter = 2;
let questioncounter_event = 1;
let currentNode = 1;
```

Comment: I think it's better to keep those variables in redux store so that it can be accessed from both of the components. And reset those values on dispatching LOGOUT_USER action

Comment: You cannot. That's what modules are all about. You can only access explicitly `export`ed items (and then you even cannot modify them). Your *ChatState.js* modules should export a function that will reset them, and your `logoutUser` function should call that.

Comment: As @BhuwanAdhikari said: the simplest approach is to use Redux, but if you wqnt to avoid it for some reason, show us your `ChatState` - `AuthState` relation (eg. file structure). In general, in React you pass data down (parent->children) with occasional callbacks to pass it up.